# How does one implement the customername.mydomain.com pattern with registering new customers?

Tags: dns

I have seen services that allow customers to setup their own name before your domain and I am wondering if there is any guidance as to how this pattern is acheived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally this has a few parts:

1. You need to set up a wildcard DNS A record pointing `*.mydomain.com` to your server / load balancer.
2. Your web server needs to handle all domains of that pattern, and use the subdomain to decide what page to serve, or what customer to use. This is very specific to the technology you are using, so it may be hard to help you without more details.

In order to handle https connections, you will need a wildcard tls certificate for `*.mydomain.com`